# How to delete a row only after inserting another row in excel using Java POI

Tags: java

i am dealing with two jframes. One for inserting and the other for deletion.
 in order to edit we need to delete the chosen record and insert a new one.
We need insertion to be done before deletion.

```
Edit(){
 Insert() //this invokes an UI and on providing new details and clicking submit will insert record into file
 Delete()  // this method deletes the record specified
}
```

The problem is since we are dealing with JFrames ,after calling edit method insert frame is initialized and record is getting deleted even before inserting.can someone please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: First, use a debugger to step through your application. Second be more specific: why are you using different JFrames for this? What happens when inserting? Who's responsible for deletion?  etc. etc.

Comment: the application is a leave tracker application.User will be provided two options one to apply and other to  edit .When user chooses edit option  he need to enter some details and on clicking edit button edit user will be given the UI through  which he can apply a leave.The approach we are using is to delete the row that matches the details and insert a new row with edited details.

Comment: Now before calling the delete function UI for apply leave will be invoked.It being a JFrame will be open and control will go to next line i.e. deletion which means no matter whether the user enters new details or not row will  be deleted.Now deletion is happening before insertion which should not be done.
Please help me with this.